# How to represent multiple related signals via mathematical function?

Tags: signal-analysis, stochastic

I have three data sets from same source. I know they are interdependent and stochastic also. The datasets are of very high frequency (see the graph, X axis is time and Y axis is value). I want to represent these three signals in a single mathematical function. Is it possible? 
[image]

In the above graph, please see there is a pattern or seasonality. If we change one then other also changes. I have tried to google for it but did not find any model that can completely represent this type of data in a single expression.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Mathematical models of signals are very easy to formulate.  However, you've said nothing that would allow us to help you with this. Please let us know: Are the signals sine waves? Are they stochastic (random)? Is there any structure at all?  What do you mean by "interdependent"? What do you mean by "very high frequency"?

Comment: I have edited @Peter-K  Hope now it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks!  I've reopened. Let's see what people come up with.

Comment: What exactly do you want the function to do?

Comment: @JimClay : I want  a mathematical expression(s) that represents these three stochastic signals, in other words if I give the input (say we have three signals a,b,c so if we input the value of a,c) then it will produce the result of b at that time quantum.

Comment: Let me try to better understand: are you trying to find a function $F$  that would  link the three signals $a(t)$, $b(t)$, $c(t)$? For instance $F(a,b,c;t) = 0$, such that a a given time $t$, knowing only $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, you are able to "invert" $F$ and find $c(t)$? And what is the purple bottom signal?

Comment: Yes @LaurentDuval you have got the correct sense but please avoid the bottom purple signal(its a signal that I am not concerned about and its some kind of noise signal)

Comment: Oscillations and peaks are relatively well phased, so assume it is instantaneous. The relation does not seem linear. I would try non-linear dimension reduction, such as non-linear PCA, or source separation techniques, to get more intuition

Comment: Would it not probability distributions speak for the random signals instead of a deterministic equation? Better find the histogram of these signal and characterize the source.

Comment: Can you provide the signals as a download, ideally as a matlab mat file of csv file?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Here it is https://goo.gl/DNE3W2

Comment: Your data contains quite a few NaNs and huge outliers. Do you have a better version?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Yes NaN is there as I am collecting the signals and saving via scripts(NaN issue cannot be solved, we fix it 0) and this is the best concise data that we have..

Comment: Hi, First of all, for what i can see, if you say the data comes from the same source, then you have a stochastic process which is not [ergodic][1]. So describing it only based on this data sets may be difficult. Could you give us a bit more explanation as to what are you trying to achieve with this compact representation that you are looking for?


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Eureqa](http://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/) software. It tries to find the simplest mathematical relation between multiple data. If the relation truly has a simple symbolic form, I think it should find it. Otherwise it will produce some strangely formulated approximation.

Comment: Thanks!! At a first glance it looks like an appealing tool ...

Comment: Eureqa gives me some strange equation when I tried it to fit other set of data it does not fit well (data from same source but on different time)..